# publishing excel interop on the server does not work

Tags: excel, interop

Working locally is fine with this:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

 Application excel = null;
 Workbook wb = null;

 excel = new Application();
 excel.Visible = false;
 excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
 excel.AlertBeforeOverwriting = false;

 wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(Server.MapPath(fileName), Type.Missing, false, 
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing,
                    Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);

wb.Save();

wb.Close(false, null, null);

excel.Quit();
```

After publishing on the server Windows 7 Ultimate x64, I got this problem:

```
Microsoft Office Excel cannot access the file: ///
There are several possible reasons: • The file name or path does not exist. • The file is being used by another program. • The workbook you are trying to save has the same name as a currently open workbook.
```

How to solve this problem:

Comment: did you manage to resolve this?  Having exactly the same problem!